# Como exibir o número de linhas na barra lateral esquerda do VBA Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Como eu faço para exibir a numeração de linhas na lateral destacada em vermelho no VBA?? sem mostrar o número de linhas fica bem confuso na hora de depurar, como eu faço para mostrar o número??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leia [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002482/7690982), mas se mesmo assim quiser, veja [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045978/7690982)

Comment: Enorme esse código, porém eu não tinha notado a presença do pequeno espaço indicando o número de linha e coluna

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente o editor VBA do Excel não possui essa opção nativa no sistema.
Teria que procurar por addons alternativos capazes de suprir esse gap, tais como: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-line-numbers/, mas nunca usei pra dizer se são realmente bons, até por serem pagos.